# An unexpected "The non-generic type cannot be used with the type arguments"?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
public abstract class SerializedDelegateBase<TDelegate, TTarget>
    where TDelegate : class
    where TTarget : class
{
   ...
}

public abstract class SerializedMBDelegateBase<TDelegate> : SerializedDelegateBase<TDelegate, MonoBehaviour> where TDelegate : class
{
   ...
}

public class ParameterizedSerializedDelegate<T> : SerializedMBDelegateBase<Action<T>> where T : EventArgs
{
   ...
}
```

And finally:

```
[Serializable]
public class OnTransitionArg : EventArgs
{
    public string TransitionName { set; get; }
}

[Serializable]
public class OnTransitionDelegate : ParameterizedSerializedDelegate<OnTransitionArg> { }
```

Now for some strange reason, I'm getting "The non-generic type 'ParameterizedSerializedDelegate' cannot be used with type arguments" on my `OnTransitionDelegate` when I'm inheriting from `ParameterizedSerializedDelegate`

I have no idea why.

Anybody?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I should probably mention that the classes are in different files. I just tried a minimal but similar setup in terms of the generic arguments in one file, it worked! - I don't know what's different about my real setup...

Comment: This works fine on my machine.  Are you sure the namespace where `ParameterizedSerializedDelegate<T>` is imported?

Comment: Well, to be honest with you - I just tried a minimal setup (in one file) very similar to what I have in terms of the generics and arguments. It worked well - for some reason that setup isn't working (in the real setup, the classes are in different files). Can you elaborate more on your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I was editing 'another' version of the `ParameterizedSerializedDelegate` file - and so the one VS was looking at was different.

Answer (score 0):

@vexe's solution worked for me but I worked out what I did to reproduce it (explanation will use original question type names).

In VS2013, this can happen when you are using the `CTRL-.` shortcut menu and not paying attention. Rather than choosing "Add << namespace >>", it is possible to select "Generate class for...", which will create a new stub class called `ParameterizedSerializedDelegate` in the same folder as `OnTransitionDelegate`.

What is confusing is that if you hit `F12` (go to definition) on `ParameterizedSerializedDelegate` in the example above, it will find the generic version of it and take you there - even if the namespace is not available in that file.